# Excessive spacing on a Weebly section

Tags: editor, weebly

My website on Weebly is divided into sections. But the gap between these two sections is unnecessarily large, and I can find no way to reduce it.
Can someone please help me to reduce the padding and to close the gap?
See the attached pictures for visuals.
[mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2XAe.jpg)
[desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb4Dm.png)

No visible help from Weebly - I can't shrink the size of the Section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the design of the Theme, there is the following CSS.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .main-wrap .container { padding: 30px 20px; }
}
```

If you would like to alter the padding for the container you can either customize the Theme by editing the CSS file - line 269 and or simply add the following to your Settings > SEO > Header Section.

```css
<style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .main-wrap .container { padding: 10px 20px; }
    }
</style>
```

Note: a change from 30px to 10px should be sufficient. Make sure to save and publish your changes.. and refresh your browser so you see the published changes.

Comment: Firstly, thank you Jeffrey, for answering my cry for help. How lovely to think there are generous people out there willing to help with something so trivial!

Comment: However, I couldn't find that CSS in my Theme - maybe my predecessor has adapted a theme and it has jigged around the CSS? 

I've tried the search function within the Weebly theme CSS, but couldn't find a line of code matching yours? Any clues you can offer?

I found this in the source code, does it teach you anything?

 <div class="wsite-section wsite-body-section wsite-background-12" style="height: auto;" >

Comment: @SamDiamond Glad to help. It looks like you found it, I see that line 269 in the CSS has changed from 30px to 10px  ...please be sure to mark my answer as the correct answer!

Comment: Huh, you think I found it?

But if I look on the homepage, do you see that yawning gap between paragraph one and the Principal's Welcome? How do I fix that? ‍♂️ 

https://www.bisc.edu.eg/

Comment: @SamDiamond I looked at the CSS via the published site, the main_style.css controlling the mobile version has changed and it reflects what I mentioned above.. however.. Somehow I had it in my head this was ONLY about the mobile version. There is also CSS at line 32 for `.main-wrap .container { padding: 60px 40px; max-width: 1366px; }`  Change 60px to 40px or something less then 40, that will alter the desktop view.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. I tried to find the CSS code, and changed it to 20px 20px, but it still didn't close the gap on the published desktop site... On this link below you can see the code I am looking at. Am I in the right place? 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12TLr-1kIaa_X803Tdxr57MpkfIElcMHT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SamDiamond That looks right.. I forgot Weebly starting using LESS CSS and a whole bunch of files, just for CSS.  I see on your published site the padding is 40px 40px now so it looks like you got it. (if you don't see changes on the published site after publishing, click CTRL + F5 on your keyboard)